# What internal method is calling in javascript when I get array element value by index?

Tags: javascript

I have some [`wtfjs`](http://wtfjs.com) code:

```
var a = [,];
alert(a.indexOf(a[0]));
```

`a.indexOf(a[0])` returns `-1`. The main point in this example is difference between `uninitialized` and `undefined` values:

`a` contains one not initialized element.

`a[0]` return `undefined`.

`a` don't contains the `undefined` value. So `a.indexOf(a[0]) === -1` is `true`.

But where I can find the explanation why `a[0]` return `undefined`? What internal method is calling?

P.S. `Undefined` is the javascript primitive type. `Uninitialized` means the value that don't have any javascript type, but there is no such primitive type in javascript.

Comment: Easy way to see the difference in arrays: `console.dir([,]); console.dir([1]);`. Expand the representation the console gives you and notice the lack of a `0` property in the first one.

Comment: It's gotta be in here somewhere... http://es5.github.io/

Comment: `var a = [undefined]; a.indexOf(undefined)` should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ES5 spec tells us the following of [array initialisers](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4):

> Elided array elements are not defined.

Note that they are *not defined*. That's different from having the value `undefined`. As you've already noticed, elided elements *do* contribute to the length of the array:

> ...the missing array element contributes to the length of the Array and increases the index of subsequent elements.

When you invoke [`indexOf`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14) on an array this is one of the steps that happens:

> Let *kPresent* be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of *O* with argument ToString(*k*).

In that, `k` is a number corresponding to an array index and `O` is the array itself. Since elided elements were not defined the array does not have a property for the corresponding index.

Comment: I knew it was in the spec somewhere :-)

Comment: It's cool.  I re-did it! :-D  I just wanted to add in a link to the `indexOf` in the spec.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. I forgot that javascript is prototype-based scripting language and Array is a object. So if there is no property `0` in `a` array, the internal engine go deeper to prototype and there is no such property in prototype chain - return `undefined`. In specification this is in `[[HasProperty]]`  description. When there is no such property `[[GetProperty]]` try to get it from prototype chain and returns `undefined` if it stops on `null`(end of prototype chains). *NB* Then I write `prototype chains` I means `__proto__` ([[Prototype]]), not `prototype` as shared properties.

Answer (score 1):

The `.indexOf()` function only examines elements of the array that have explicitly been set. Therefore, in this case, even though the length of the array is 1 (or 2, depending on the browser involved), there are no explicitly-set elements, so the effective length is zero.

Another way of seeing this effect:

```
var a = [,];
console.log(a.length); // 1 (in Firefox)
console.log('0' in a); // false
```

That means that even though the length of the array is 1, there is no element with index 0. Thus, any explicit reference to examine the value of `a[0]` will have the value `undefined`.

Now, if we play a little more:

```
a[0] = undefined;
console.log(a.length); // still 1
console.log('0' in a); // true !!
```

Once the property reference has appeared on the left side of an assignment, it becomes "real" even if its (now explicit) value is `undefined`.

As for the "internal methods" involved, you can check [the Reference Specification type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7), and in particular how its "Get" operation works.

Comment: That wasn't his question.

Comment: @Barmar I don't really know what the question is, but it seemed to be about the "wtfjs" conundrum involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one.  For instance, if you set a = [,,1] and examine the array, you'll see that only the index of 2 has a value, and it is 1.  Index 0 & 1 have no value at all, they were implicitly set to undefined.  In other words, they are NOT DEFINED.  If you search for a value of undefined in an array, it will always return -1.  If you instead set them explicitly to null, you'll see your index come back.

To directly address your question, a.indexOf(a[0]) returns -1 because a[0] is undefined.

Comment: "Index 0 & 1 have no value at all, they were explicitly set to undefined" - no. They were not set at all: `console.dir([,,1])`

Answer (score 0):

All elements of an array which are not defined as a value (including null) are undefined.

When you define an array like this:

```
var a = [,null,];
```

Elements a[0] and a[2] are undefined. Any index you use into the array `a` will return undefined except `a[1]` which is null. The length property of an array is one higher than the highest non-undefined index. For example:

```
var b = [];
b[10] = null;
b.length
> 11
```

However the only index which will not return undefined is `b[10]`.

You can read more about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ez24f2(v=vs.94).aspx

I am not sure what you mean by uninitialized - I think that concept is captured by `undefined` in JavaScript.

Comment: That statement about the length is incorrect - the length can be set to anything you like.

Comment: Further information about array length: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length